# Where do i find the config for guix in quemu?

Tags: guix

I started guix with:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
   -nic user,model=virtio-net-pci \
   -enable-kvm -m 2048 \
   -device virtio-blk,drive=myhd \
   -drive if=none,file=guix-system-vm-image-1.4.0.x86_64-linux.qcow2,id=myhd
```

How do i find my config.

I checked this path (
scm file is in the target path ( ~/. config/guix/channels.), but i could not find any config.

Also i checked at /etc/config according to this post: https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/After-System-Installation.html#After-System-Installation but i could not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still quite new to the platform and have just started to use it as a Virtual Machine on my OpenBSD host.

To my current knowledge - which as I just pointed out is stil quite limited - there isn't really anything special about that `/etc/config.scm` path (other than for instance `/etc/guix/channels.scm`, which seems to be an actual default / fallback path).  In fact, I am currently using `/etc/guix/config.scm`.

However, `/run/current-system/configuration.scm` seems to always contain the current configuration - and there is also `/run/current-system/channels.scm`.

To modify the configuration, simply copy that `/run/current-system/configuration.scm` to a place of your choice, edit it and then do `guix system reconfigure <place-where-you-copied-it-to>`.